# HTTP Request Connector mule

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have a web service provider and consumer flows both in same project since I am testing in local. In my consumer flow, I have a HTTP Request connector which is supposed to hit the provider flow but the problem is while debugging it shows timeout to hit the provider flow  and if I step over again it hits the provider flow. Also after the provider flow is executed, the control doesnt come back to consumer flow.
 Here is HTTP connector config:

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" basePath="/api" connectionIdleTimeout="10000000" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>


<http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="/PatientAdmission" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Am I missing something?

Below is the provider HTTP listener config

```
<http:listener-config name="api-httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" metadata:id="426556ee-3ad8-4231-8c4c-ce3922720e6a" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Comment: Show your flow which expose the service, so that the consumer connector can be configured

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using the below listener configuration and check whether it helps (and let the http request config be the same):

```
<http:listener-config name="api-httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" basePath="api"/>
<http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Thanks,
Shijil.R.K

Comment: Also control is not going back to consumer flow after the POST is done

Answer (score 0):

After setting the response codes in the provider HTTP Listener config and consumer HTTP Request config, the response came back to consumer flow.